# Convert PHP myadmin time string to local time zone(IST) with proper format with moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to display a GMT date time string to  IST(GMT +0530) time format by using moment.js. I am assigning the PHP date time value to a javascript variable and then converting the GMT time to IST time using `moment.tz().format();` method.  But when I alert the converted value by specifying the format parameters ,the alert is showing the formatted time with chinese letters. moment.js is clearly confusing. Please help me solve this...

- GMT Datetime value is `"2014-11-28 20:15:26"` which is i am getting from PHP variable
- `"2014-11-29T01:45:26+05:30"` is value of Converted value of date time variable to IST by using `moment.tz(m,zone).format();`
- `"11月 29日 2014 1:45 早上"` is the value  of converted value with format parameters `moment.tz(m,zone).format('MMM Do YYYY h:mm a');`

My code is

```
var start_dates = '<?php echo $times_start; ?>';
var zone = "Asia/Kolkata";
var m = moment.tz(start_dates,'Europe/London').format();
var time = moment.tz(m,zone).format('MMM Do YYYY h:mm a');
```

Comment: Timezones have nothing to do with the output formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you could get Chinese characters is if you have set the Chinese locale with either the `lang` or `locale` functions.  You might have done that somewhere else in your script.

With regard to the code you wrote, that interprets the input as the time in London - which is not the same thing as GMT or UTC.   (London alternates between GMT and BST for daylight saving time.)

You also don't need to format it just to parse it again.

You just need to do this:

```
var m = moment.utc(start_dates);
var time = m.tz(zone).format('MMM Do YYYY h:mm a');
```

This will work for any of the supported zones.   But if you know for a fact that you will always be converting to Indian Standard Time, since it doesn't use DST, you don't really need moment-timezone.  You can just do this:

```
var m = moment.utc(start_dates);
var time = m.utcOffset("+05:30").format('MMM Do YYYY h:mm a');
```

Comment: I didn't mention any locale or lang functions anywhere in my script.In fact i dont know about those things because i am using moment js for the first time and i have no idea about those things.Anyway thanks for the head starts .I will try it and let you know if that thing occurs again. @Matt Johnson